# Contact Merging - Getting 'resourceName' of deleted Contact from Merge

Tags: google-people-api

When merging 2 Contacts together, is there a way to find the 'resourceName' of the Contact that was deleted (Merged into the resulting Contact)?

Contact A - people/12345
Contact B - people/23456

Merging 'B' into 'A'. Resulting Contact is 'A' (people/12345). Is there a way to determine what Contact got merged into Contact A, and a result, deleted? I'd love to find that Contact B (people/23456) was the Contact that merged into Contact A (people/12345) so I can make link and association adjustments on our own end of things.

It doesn't appear that "previousResourceNames" does what I first thought it did (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#personmetadata)

Any insight on a possible solution would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: How did you merge the contacts? Programmatically?

Comment: Or do you mean retrieivng the [merged view](https://developers.google.com/people) ?